# Hibernate Dao class is too slow

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, dao

In my restful application i noticed a problem with dao class speed. Each call transaction takes about 0.12-0.18s for about 10 small records selected. But i need to  call many times different dao class in one request.

```
public class ShellDao {

public ShellDao(){}

public List<Object[]> getBackgroundImages() {

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        session = HibernateAnnotationUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        String hql = "SELECT1";
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
        List<Object[]> result = query.list();
        tx.commit();
        if (result.size() != 0) {
            return result;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            tx.rollback();
        } catch (RuntimeException rbe) {
            rbe.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
            long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
            Double time = (stopTime-startTime)/ 1000000000.0;
            System.out.println(time);
        }
    }
}
```

Is ther any method to avoid calling beginTransaction every time? Becouse it takes about 0.062275091s.

Comment: How large is the network latency for your sql execution?

Comment: How Much time query taking if you run it directly from DB Console?

Comment: Latency is about 21-25ms
I can not connect with db server through ssh, any other idea how to check query time on server side?

Comment: Do you use a connection pool?

Comment: That `SELECT1` isn't your real query, is it? What's your real query?

Comment: My real query take similar time, so it's not problem with query. Execute only query takes 0.02s, its good time, beginTransaction take most of time in this class.